# $PATH not being set in .bash_profile

Tags: bash, macos, path

I use the MACOS Catalina 10.15.4. I am trying to set the PATH variable in the ~/.bash_profile.

```
# Setting PATH for Python 3.7
# The original version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
export PATH="$PATH:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin"
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/some_user/Desktop/path_to_some_folder/bin"
# added by Anaconda3 2018.12 installer
# >>> conda init >>>
# !! Contents within this block are managed by 'conda init' !!
__conda_setup="$(CONDA_REPORT_ERRORS=false '/anaconda3/bin/conda' shell.bash hook 2> /dev/null)"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    \eval "$__conda_setup"
else
    if [ -f "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh" ]; then
        . "/anaconda3/etc/profile.d/conda.sh"
        CONDA_CHANGEPS1=false conda activate base
    else
        \export PATH="/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
    fi
fi
unset __conda_setup
# <<< conda init <<<
```

However, when I echo $PATH on the terminal I get the following:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/Current/Commands
```

I checked my path is only being set from /etc/paths and /etc/paths.d.
How do I make sure that PATH is set from the .bash_profile file as well?

Also, I have .bash_profile-anaconda3.bak, .bash_sessions and .bash_history in my home directory if it makes any difference.

EDIT: I tried exporting PATH in .bashrc but that did not work either.

Comment: If this is a new account, you aren't running `bash`, but `zsh`. You should be using `.zprofile` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @chepner, since all the new accounts on macOS use zsh now. I reconfigured my path using .zprofile.